# What is the probability that a psychic correctly "predicts" the outcome of at least 5 out of 10 coin flips?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Assume the psychic is actually just randomly guessing on each flip.

---

The attempt:

- let E be the event in question
- number of outcomes per flip = 2
- chance of correctly guessing the correct outcome = $ \frac{1}{2}$
- notice the key word "at least": indicates that we should be doing a summation
- You can get exactly 5 correct, exactly 6, ..., all the way to exactly 10 correct

$$ P(E) = \sum_{i=5}^{10} (\frac{1}{2^i})= 63/1024$$

---

What is wrong with this approach?
My intuition says that the probability should be $ \frac{1}{2} $.

Comment: Yes, but remember that you can get *any* 5 correct, *any* 6 correct, etc, so you need to multiply by 10 choose 5 for 1/32, 10 choose 6 for 1/64, and so on. Another way to see why your solution is wrong: what are the chances the psychic will be *wrong* on 5 or more flips? Computing it your way would give 63/1024, which means the total probability is 126/1024, which is less than 1.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: $$ P(E) = \sum_{i=5}^{10} (\frac{1}{2^i}\[\begin{matrix}
        10 \\
        x \\
        \end{matrix}\]= 12585/1024 $$

Comment: @RichardJ keyword: Binomial Distribution $$P(E) = \sum_{i=5}^{10} \dbinom{10}{i} \dfrac 1 {2^{10}} = \dfrac {315} {512}$$  Remember, that's, 5 correct & 5 incorrect or 6 correct & 4 incorrect or...

Comment: Thanks! Am I correct to believe that binomial distribution is restricted to use in situations where there are only two possible outcomes per trial?

Comment: Yes,  A Binomial Distribution, $\mathcal{Bin}(n,p)$, counts the number of favoured outcomes in a sequence of $n$ Bernoulli (ie succeed-or-fail) trials with trial success probability $p$.  If there are more than one disjoint kind of 'success' per trial use a Multinomial Distribution.

Answer (score 3):

The probability for each sequence of coin flips is $\frac{1}{2^{10}}$.

There are $\binom{10}{k}$ sequences in which exactly $k$ predictions are correct (because there are $\binom{10}{k}$ ways to select the $k$ flips which are different from the psychic's guess).

Therefore you want $\sum\limits_{i=5}^{10}\binom{10}{i}/2^{10}$.

Using symmetry of the binomial coefficient this is equal to $\frac{2^{10}+\binom{10}{5}}{2}/2^{10}=\frac{1}{2}+\binom{10}{5}/2^{11}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{252}{2048}\approx0.62$

Comment: Is the numerator equal to the number of ways in which we can have at least 5 correct guesses?

Comment: yes${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

The probability of guessing exactly 5 results is $\dbinom{10}{5}\dfrac 1 {2^{10}}$.  That is $\dfrac {63}{216}$.

The probability of guessing more than 5 results is $\dfrac{193}{512}$ and of guessing less than 5 results is $\dfrac{193}{512}$

Thus the probability of the 'psychic' guessing *at least* 5 of 10 coins is $\dfrac{319}{512}$.

That is the confidence trick.   By including the not too unlikely possibility of "exactly 5", the 'psychic' gains an advantage over your intuition's estimate of $\tfrac 12$.